# TypeError: run() missing 1 required positional argument: 'fetches' on Session.run()

Tags: python, windows, tensorflow

I'm new at tensorflow and I'm trying to follow [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/get_started) getting started tutorial. But executing this very simple code within "ex001.py" script:

```
import tensorflow as tf

sess = tf.Session
hello = tf.constant('Hello, TensorFlow!')
print(hello)
print(sess.run(hello))
```

I get the following output

> Tensor("Const:0", shape=(), dtype=string)
>       Traceback (most recent call last):
>         File "C:\Users\Giuseppe\Desktop\ex001.py", line 6, in 
>           print(sess.run(hello))
>       TypeError: run() missing 1 required positional argument: 'fetches'

I've checked the [tf.Session.run()](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Session#run) syntax but looks right and I didn't find anyone with the same issue.

I'm running with this configuration:

- Windows 7 Professional sp1 64 bit
- Python 3.5.3 64 bit
- Tensorflow 1.0.1 cpu version

Thanks in advance

Comment: Not `sess = tf.Session`, it is `tf.Session()`, you missing `()`

Comment: @xxi avoid answering questions in comments :) You should make that an answer.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Not `sess = tf.Session`, it should be `tf.Session()`, you are missing `()`

Answer (score 0):

sess = tf.Session line has incorrect syntax of Session.
It should be

sess = tf.Session()

() is missing.